# CME error Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined

Tags: web8, cme

On the Content Manager Explorer of a SDL Web 8.1 instance I get an error when I use the "View on Site" button on any page.

On the same instance this button used to work.

I tried to close&open the browser, and tried on a different machine but the issue remains.

This is the error message from the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined
    at eval (/WebUI/Editors/Base/Libraries/Knockout/knockout.bindinghandlers.js:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:1)
    at JsFileHandler._render (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:3)
    at JsFileHandler.o.render (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:3)
    at Function.o.renderWhenLoaded (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:3)
    at eval (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:3)
    at Object.eval (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:3)
    at c (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (/SDL/Common/Library/Core/Packages/SDL.Client.Core.js:2)
/WebUI/Editors/Base/Libraries/Knockout/knockout.bindinghandlers.js:1
```

What could cause this issue?

Comment: After a restart of IIS and all content manager services the problem was resolved. I do not know what the root cause was.

Comment: recently any GUI extensions/hotfix deployment anything happened on CME server?

Comment: @Velmurugan I have an ECL extension, but that has been stable for a while.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hotfix available for this:
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000006841

It is also fixed in 8.5 version.